# How can I print the value of a Port Number?

Tags: c++, unix, network-programming

Trying to get a program to return an IP address along with a port number so I can create an effective TCP Client/Server program. Struggling with the function getaddrinfo() at the moment and understand that the 2nd argument in the function is what designates the port number. I can get it to return an IP but can't get it to return a port number. I'm inputting the host name and port designation (ex. http or telnet) in string form and trying to get back an IP address and port number associated with it.

I've tried inputting AI_NUMERICSERV into ai.flags in order to input the numeric value of the port number besides specifying "http" and "telnet". Just trying to understand network programming for the first time.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    //  hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;//leaving this off for now

    if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res)) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }
    `for(p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {        
    void *addr;

    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
    addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    printf("%s\n", ipstr);
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]); //displays IP correctly
    printf("Port for %s: ", argv[2]); // doesn't display port number
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

I keep expecting a port number output next to IP address output but I always get just the IP address and not the port number.

Comment: What are the parameters you pass to your program? AFAIK, `getaddrinfo` doesn't modify first two arguments, so you should print back your arguments.

Comment: Why aren't you using `*res` to read the results of `getaddrinfo`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the port(s) returned by `res->ai_addr`...

```
printf("port=%h\n", ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)(res->ai_addr)) ->sin_port));
```

If you are just trying to figure out what port(s) are associated with specific services, and you are on a *nix host, you can also just grep `/etc/services`.

Comment: `res->ai_addr->sin_port` doesn't compile, because `sin_port` is a field of `sockaddr_in` but `ai_addr` is a `sockaddr*`. So you need to typecast `ai_addr` to `sockaddr_in*` to access the `sin_addr` and `sin_port` fields: `reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(res->ai_addr)->sin_port`

Comment: I know.  It would probably made more sense to just use `ipv4` from the example code although I wanted to emphasize the result is in `res`.